# ¿Eliminar ordenado automático Datatables JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Tengo un problema, estoy utilizando el plugin de JQuery datatable para armar unas tablas, el problema es que no deseo que me ordene los datos que coloco en las tablas, estas tablas las armo dinámicamente con unos datos que tengo en una matriz en JS, y quiero que tal y como la arma inicialmente se quede ordenada :/

El código de los datatables que tengo es este:

```
$("#TLunesVer").dataTable({
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "paging": false,
            "ordering": false,
            "info": false,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 1000,
            "bDestroy": true
        });
```

ya use

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
          { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] }
        ]
```

pero sigue ordenandolas, eso solo le elimina la opción para que la persona las ordene ascendente o decentemente.

Como ya dije, yo no quiero que se ordenen, que tal como coloque la información, así mismo se quede, que no ordene nada.

Comment: Si, eso sirve, muchas gracias, si quieres coloca la respuesta y te califico como que es la correcta :)

Comment: Elimina la cache del navegador o la pagina después de haber hecho los cambios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

de acuerdo a la siguiente [respuesta aceptada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124746) en ingles debes establecer un arreglo vació para que des-habilite  el ordenado automático con la opcion:

```
"aaSorting": []
```

Comment: Super, funciona de maravilla